# Logout with facebook

Tags: c#, .net, facebook

How can I log a user out from my facebook connect website, without using the fb-login button? I would like to do it from codebehind (c#)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out that there was only an option to do it from Javascript by `FB.logout()`. It seems kinda wird that there is no API from codebehind to do the same.

Comment: He explicitly asked for a server side method not by javascript

Answer (score 7):

If you just want a simple link to log out the user, you can form a url like this:

`https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&confirm=1&next=REDIRECT`

Just replace `ACCESS_TOKEN` and `REDIRECT` with the appropriate values.  Facebook changes this every now and then, so you have to watch out for that.  This only works in the browser, but the nice thing about doing it this way is that the user doesn't have to wait for the JavaScript library to load.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this from an instance of the facebook.API class(facebook.dll).
Just call _api.LogOff()

Comment: what facebook API class are you talking about?   i'm assuming it's one of the many old libraries that don't use the oAuth 2.0 API.  the latest has no logOff method: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/395

Answer (score 2):

My painful experience showed me you MUST have a return(false); after the FB.Connect.logout(); call like in :

FB.Connect.logout(doOnUserLogout()); return(false);

Otherwise it'll seem like it is logging out, with the modal dialog box stating so, but it will not log the user out.

I found this out by chance as it was again not documented.

Comment: I assume you're calling this method from inside a button/link?  If that's the case, that's why the "return false" is required.  It's not missing in the facebook documentation - if you want to prevent a link/button's default action (ex. the href) from executing, you will need to return false, otherwise it will navigate before your onclick handler finishes.

Answer (score 2):

seems ConnectSession doesn't have any codes in Logout methd. Its just

```
void Logout(){ }
```

without anything. same for `Login(){}`

so basically you will need to use the java-script version

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it possible with curl and something like preg_match("/a href=\"\/logout.php(.*?)\"/", $page, $logout_param);

then...

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://m.facebook.com/logout.php' . $logout_param[1]);
curl_exec($ch);

??

Answer (score 0):

At least in the php api there is a logout method. In order for it to work the logout method redirects the user to an url in facebook.com and then redirects you back to your site

$facebook->logout( "http://site.com/returnAfterLogout.php" )

However i have found that in that request the javascript api still thinks the
php api still thinks he is logged in and until you try to do an api request it will
raise an exception.

Comment: This was a question related to the .Net version of facebook api, and not php.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this in a Webview using:

```
 webview.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com/logout.php?confirm=1");
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me, it doesn't even work through a browser for me.