# facebook api - How to expire current session?

Tags: facebook

```
//file test.php

require_once 'config.php';

if($fb->get_loggedin_user())
{

        // step1 do something

        //step2 expire session    
}
else
{
    //FB coonect login button
}
```

I need to expire session after i am done with the step1 in the above code. But $facebook->get_loggedin_user() always returns a user id and never goes into else part.

I tried `$fb->clear_cookie_state(); $fb->api_client->user=0; $fb->api_client->session_key=null; $fb->logout('index.php');`

Nothing is seems to be working. please help. How can i make him log out??

Comment: "Logout with Facebook," http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658027/logout-with-facebook

Comment: I had a good answer on this before...maybe this will help you out. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386557/how-to-log-out-users-using-facebook-connect-in-php-and-zend/1386749#1386749](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386557/how-to-log-out-users-using-facebook-connect-in-php-and-zend/1386749#1386749)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this through Facebook's "RESTful API" which is what the PHP client library interfaces with. You can, however, accomplish this with Facebook's "JavaScript API" which includes the functions `FB.Connect.logout()` and `FB.Connect.logoutAndRedirect(url)`. Calling either of these functions on any Facebook canvas page or FB Connect page will expire the user's current Facebook session.